# How to override custom placeholder css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that needed placeholders when viewing from a mobile screen. I didnt need them in desktop mode so I added some css that has the font white until the screen resolution breaks to mobile. then it changes the color so it is visible. problem is there are some textareas that i need to show the placeholders while in desktop mode. How can i override the css in the stylesheet?

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
color:    #FFFFFF !important;
}
input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder { 
color:    #FFFFFF !important;
}
input::-moz-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder { 
color:    #FFFFFF !important;
}
 input:-ms-input-placeholder, textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { 
color:    #FFFFFF !important;
}
@media (max-width: 1070px) {
 input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
color:    #737373 !important;
}
 input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder { 
color:    #737373 !important;
 }
input::-moz-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder { 
color:    #737373 !important;
 }
input:-ms-input-placeholder, textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { 
color:    #737373 !important;
 }
 }
```

Comment: You could toggle a CSS class on the textarea tags using JavaScript. Define the class holding the desired color in your stylesheet.

Comment: how to do I add the input:: css to a class? What is the correct format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a visible class

```css
.visible::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 color:    #000 !important;
}
```

add the above class to the textarea's where you need to display placeholder